# SublimeLinter-php not showing unused code

Tags: php, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimelinter

I'm using SublimeLinter-php and it works great overall but it's not showing unused code. From use statements, unused variables, etc, which is really annoying...

How can I make it show that?

I also read about phpmd but I can't seem to get it working no matter what I do...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

probably you need to download this plugin to detect PHP
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-php

Comment: I'm using this plugin exactly, it works but it doesn't detect unused code... And that's what I wrote in my question.

Comment: phpmd.org will show unused code. there is a SublimeLinter-phpmd extension as well. Just install both SublimeLinter and this extension, open the User preferences for SublimeLinter, and reduce the phpmd rulesets to just "rulesets": "unusedcode" to avoid over reporting on conventions and such you might not use., maybe you also need to follow this question as its duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679370/identifying-php-unused-and-undefied-variables-sublime